# Single Sign on (SSO) not working on Firefox

Tags: group-policy, adfs, single-sign-on, firefox, ntlm

Could it be that Firefox doesn’t support all windows NTLM SSO scenarios on a Sharepoint Site via adfs?  Login attempts into Sharepoint site just gets stuck on the login page and nothing happens afterwards… I enabled Windows SSO gpo, not sure if that was needed.I also activated the following policies below but nothing changed.

Added the Sharepoint Site address used by my users to access the internal SPR or federation Server sites, not sure if additional addresses will be required.

> - network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
> - network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris
> - network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris signon.autologin.proxy to be true

Or I need to set

> - activate security.enterprise_roots.enabled

If I am using an internal CA in order to use trusted roots certs from Windows though not tried that yet.

Or something like this needs to be activated the server side i.e. federation server =>  https://cloudrun.co.uk/adfs/single-sign-on-ssowith-chrome-firefox-and-adfs-4-0/

Surprisingly enough this same Sharepoint site works flawlessly on an alternative Edge chromium browser after testing on it.